# List elements doesn't change when using ToUpper function

Tags: c#, list, collections

I want to change list elements to upper case.But this code take error.Can you help me?

```
List<string> fruit = new List<string>();
fruit.Add("apple");
fruit.Add("cherry");
fruit.Add("orange");

fruit.ForEach(
    delegate(string s)
        {
            s = s.ToUpper();
        }
    );
fruit.ForEach(

    delegate(string s)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }
   );
```

Comment: Why do you still use anonymous `delegate`? better use `lambda expression`, anonymous `delegate` is just obsolete.

Comment: This is more readable and works: `for (int i = 0; i < fruits.Count; i++) fruits[i] = fruits[i].ToUpper();`

Answer (score 1):

Strings are immutable - `ToUpper` doesn't change the string - a new one is created. The original fruit List still references the old strings - your `ForEach` / `ToUpper()` code has no effect.

You will need to either remove the old and add the new string from fruit, or better still IMO, reproject the entire list into a new list, and then the new fruit list can be assigned,

i.e.

```
fruit = fruit.Select(s => s.ToUpper()).ToList();
fruit.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
List<string> fruit = new List<string>();
fruit.Add("apple");
fruit.Add("cherry");
fruit.Add("orange");
fruit = fruit.Select(x=> x.ToUpper()).ToList();
fruit.ForEach(delegate(string s)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(s);
                    }
              );
```

Note: as pointed in comments above code will create a new List and assign to fruit variable. If you don't wanna replace fruit variable then try the following.

```
var upperList = fruit.Select(x => x.ToUpper());
fruit.Clear();
fruit.AddRange(upperList);
```

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it appear as if you can do this. For example, when you write this code, the compiler actually creates a new string object to hold the new sequence of characters

```
string b = "h";
b += "ello";
```

From [Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)

Comment: Note that this will not modify the original list, but simply reassign a new list on the variable reference. Albeit probably unlikely, but it's possible that the original list is still being referenced elsewhere with lower case values. Just something for Zamir to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

`string` is immutable. You should do it in a `for` loop:

```
List<string> fruit = new List<string>();

fruit.Add("apple");
fruit.Add("cherry");
fruit.Add("orange");

for(int i = 0; i < fruit.Count; i++)
{
    fruit[i] = fruit[i].ToLower();
}
```

Or you can create new `List<string>` with correct items and replace `fruit` reference:

```
fruit = fruit.Select(x => x.ToLower()).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you mean `.ToUpper()` :)

Comment: @ChrisSinclair Actually, the question is not clear - there is `ToLower()` in title and `ToUpper()` in sample code...

Comment: Oh my yes. In the sample code it uses `ToUpper` and states "I want to change list elements to upper case", but the _title_ says `ToLower`. (I feel that they do want to use `.ToUpper` though)

Answer (score 0):

Try this with a for loop

```
List<string> fruit = new List<string>();
            fruit.Add("apple");
            fruit.Add("cherry");
            fruit.Add("orange");

            for( int i = 0; i < fruit.Count; i++ ) {

                Console.WriteLine(fruit[i].ToUpper()); // To Check
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fruit = fruit.Select(x => x.ToUpper()).ToList();
```

You're better off projecting the elements into a new list. No reason to make the code ugly with your use of delegates either. Just use the lambda syntax:

```
fruit.ForEach(s => Console.WriteLine(s));
```

or alternatively

```
foreach(var s in fruit)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start by noting that `s.ToUpper()`, as is, doesn't actually change `s`. This would not be possible as strings in C# are immutable, as many of the others answers mentioned. I assume you're aware of this, since you did `s = s.ToUpper()`.

A `List` contains references to items.

`ForEach` gives you copies of these references (stored in `s` in this case).

When you reassign `s`, you don't change the original reference, only the copy `s`.

If you were to modify `s` (i.e. `s.someModifyingFunction()`) (as opposed to reassigning it, i.e. `s = ...`), since `s` references the same object as the original reference, this would actually change the list.

Using a simple regular for-loop as mentioned by MarcinJuraszek should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < fruit.Count; i++)
    fruit[i] = fruit[i].ToUpper();
```

**To picture it, think of it this way:**

The objects are books.

The list contains a bunch of students who are each pointing to a book.

When you do `ForEach`, you get a new student pointing to the same book as one of the students in the list.

When you reassign `s`, you ask the new student to point to a different book. The student in the list is still pointing to the same book as before.

When you modify `s`, you write in the book (since it's the same book, the student in the list will still point to the book with these changes).